# Single Post Navigation Within Each Category

Tags: posts

I have about 10 different category posts etc.

As you know, withing each category there is the next and previous navigation to toggle between posts. When you reach the Last post in a category, the next navigation then takes you to the NEXT category...

My question is, is there there a way to loop only withing the category with the next and previous?

```
    // The Category Loop



if (function_exists('childtheme_override_category_loop'))  {
    function thematic_category_loop() {
        childtheme_override_category_loop();
    }
} else {
    function thematic_category_loop() {

        while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 

                thematic_abovepost(); ?>

                <div id="post-<?php the_ID();
                    echo '" ';
                    if (!(THEMATIC_COMPATIBLE_POST_CLASS)) {
                        post_class();
                        echo '>';
                    } else {
                        echo 'class="';
                        thematic_post_class();
                        echo '">';
                    }
                    thematic_postheader(); ?>
                    <div class="entry-content">
<?php thematic_content(); ?>

                    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
                    <?php thematic_postfooter(); ?>
                </div><!-- #post -->

            <?php 

                thematic_belowpost();

        endwhile;
    }
} // end category_loop
```

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem with one of my sites and i used this hack:
on your themes category.php (or if your doesn't have one then archive.php )
before the loop part witch is something like this:

```
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
```

add this code

```
if (is_category()){
     $category = $current_category = single_cat_title("", false); 
    if(isset(get_query_var( 'page' ))){
        $page = get_query_var( 'page' );
    }
    else{
        $page = 1;
    }
    global $wp_query;
    query_posts(
        array_merge(
            array( 'cat' => $category, 'paged' => $page ),
            $wp_query->query
        )
    );
}
```

this should loop only within the category.

Comment: Ok, I tried it and this is the error I get "Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in"

Comment: paste your category.php code here

Comment: I added it to my original posting, since I could not add that many characters.

Comment: that's nothing to do with the query but the custom functions the theme uses or you not really sure like post_class() ,             thematic_belowpost(); ,thematic_post_class(); so i can't help you here
just try to remove them and the code above while (have_posts()) : the_post(); and add the code i posted

Answer (score 0):

This is what i use in my child themes functions file at this time which only links posts within each category.

```
add_action('your_hook', 'wpsites_nav_links', 25 );
function wpsites_nav_links() {
if( !is_single() ) 
return;

previous_post_link('<span class="single-post-nav previous-post-link">%link</span>', '&lt;&lt; Previous Post in Category', TRUE);
next_post_link('<span class="single-post-nav next-post-link">%link</span>', 'Next Post in Category &gt;&gt;', TRUE);
}
```

Replace your_hook with your themes after content hook or use [`the_content`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) filter.