# post_prev & post_next within same category

Tags: themes

In my single blog view, I only want to show the Prior and Next buttons within the same category the current post is in.

I thought I could just change these two lines thus (set first term to true). but that doesn't seem to ever display the buttons. Any suggestions ?

```
$post_prev = get_adjacent_post(false,'',true)  ? get_permalink(get_adjacent_post(false,'',true))  : false;
$post_next = get_adjacent_post(false,'',false) ? get_permalink(get_adjacent_post(false,'',false)) : false;
```

Thank in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Single Post Navigation Within Each Category](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7232/single-post-navigation-within-each-category)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in your functions file and it links all single posts within the same category

```
add_action('loop_end', 'wpsites_nav_links', 25 );
function wpsites_nav_links() {
if( !is_single() ) 
return;

previous_post_link('<span class="single-post-nav previous-post-link">%link</span>', '&lt;&lt; Previous Post in Category', TRUE);
next_post_link('<span class="single-post-nav next-post-link">%link</span>', 'Next Post in Category &gt;&gt;', TRUE);
}
```